# Redondear Decimal Python

Tags: python

Tengo un método que me devuelve dos reales (float) con infinitos decimales, y me gustaría poder redondearlos a 4 decimales para que sean representantes.

Los reales devueltos son los siguientes

> -0.9999260022512232, 
>   0.7499415829903138

La sentencia para redondear es la siguiente, donde "solucion" contiene los dos reales anteriores:

```
"{0:.4f}".format(float(solucion))
```

Sin embargo, con el código anterior, la solución presentada es:

> -0.9999, 0.7499

Me gustaría dejar la solución representada de la siguiente manera:

> -1.0000, 0.7500

¿Alguna idea de como poder modificar o añadir para poder presentarlo de esta manera?

Comment: Para que querés tener 4 posiciones decimales si no las vas a usar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python tiene la función `round()` a la que le pasas el número que quieres redondear y el peso de la cifra a la que quieres hacer el redondeo.

El problema es que si redondeas al cuarto decimal, no obtienes lo que quieres:

```
>>> round(-0.9999260022512232, 4)
-0.9999
>>> round(0.7499415829903138, 4)
0.7499
```

Y no es que Python se haya equivocado, pues realmente la cifra después del cuarto decimal es menor que 5, por lo que el redondeo es correcto. 0.74994 redondeado a cuatro decimales es 0.7499 y no 0.7500 como tú querías.

Parece que, o bien tienes un error de concepto sobre el redondeo, o lo que realmente quieres es el número redondeado a dos cifras significativas, pero representado con cuatro decimales.

En ese caso, 0.74994... se redondearía en dos cifras como 0.75, y después, representando esa cantidad con cuatro decimales tendrías 0.7500.

Esto puedes lograrlo así:

```
>>> "{0:.4f}".format(round(0.7499415829903138, 2))
'0.7500'
```

No obstante déjame insistir en que este resultado no es correcto. Proporcionando cuatro cifras en los decimales estás dando a entender que tienes esa *precisión*, es decir, que la representación es exacta hasta el cuarto decimal, cuando en realidad has redondeado al segundo. Es más exacto `0.7499`, o en todo caso `0.75` (sin añadir los dos ceros posteriores que llamarían a engaño).